# Is there a way in arcpy to convert map units from feet to decimal degrees?

Tags: arcpy

This is my problem:
I have an arcpy script that finds the XMax, XMin, YMax, and YMin of a polygon. It shows the results in feet, but I want them to be in decimal degrees.

In ArcMap I can change the data frame's display units to decimal degrees. But every time I run my script it shows the numbers in feet again.

Is there a solution for this in arcpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a [SearchCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/SearchCursor/000v00000039000000/) on the layer holding the polygon, and specify a spatial reference:

> When specified, features will be projected on the fly using the spatial_reference provided.

See the help file under [Setting a cursor's spatial reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_a_cursor_s_spatial_reference/002z0000001w000000/) for more info on setting up the search cursor with a new coordinate system. Once you've defined the cursor, you can find the projected extent using:

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureclass,query,spatialReference)
row = rows.next()
polygon = row.shape
extent = polygon.extent
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get an answer by using a SearchCursor (as per @StephenLead 's answer above) you could look at downloading the [pyproj library](https://code.google.com/p/pyproj/). As long as you know the relevant definition of your projection (which you can get from [www.spatialreference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org/)), you can easily convert from one projection to another. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyproj

lonlat = np.array[[135.5, 135.4], [-47.5, -47.6]] #replace with your own data

vicgrid94 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3111') #replace this with your own projection
gda94 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4283') #Australian geographic coordinate system
                                      #WGS84 = epsg:4326 for comparison

#first option
xy = pyproj.transform(gda94, vicgrid94, lonlat[0], lonlat[1])

#first option
print vicgrid94(xy[0], xy[1], inverse=True) #With inverse=True transforms coordinates
                                            #in projection to lat long
                                            #Note: floating point error will be obvious
```